# How to make CSS tooltip stay up strictly while over original item, not also over newly generated tooltip?

Tags: css, hover, tooltip

I only want the tooltip text to remain while the user is STRICTLY hovering over the original element, but it by default also stays while no longer hovering over the original element if the user is hovering over the tooltip text body generated by the hover.  So how can (if possible) I make the tooltip text disappear once the user moves the cursor to be no longer over the original element with the hover styling even though the cursor may still be hovering over the tooltip text?

Sadly, I can't even imagine what to attempt to change this behavior so my code is exactly the same (in all relevant ways) as that provided by w3schools on how to make/use a tooltip.  The code is below or you can go to their link here -  https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip

```
<style>
  .tooltip {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
 }

 .tooltip .tooltiptext {
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 120px;
   background-color: black;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 6px;
   padding: 5px 0;

   /* Position the tooltip */
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
 }

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
   visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding some more meaningful tags could help to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and I wanted to put more! ...I'm just not sure what else to put.  I was also prevented from putting the tag "tooltiptext" because I don't have enough reputation.  I never really ask questions so any advice would be great if you're willing to offer.

Comment: The css tag should help already, because people use many different languages here on SO. If you posted code that documents your current attempts, that would even be better. Unfortunately I can't help you on the specific topic.

Comment: You've helped a lot anyway! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself!

My solution was to take care of the visibility styling with JavaScript instead of CSS so that I could have more control of conditionally rendering the tooltiptext. 
I also fancied it up a little and my solution is a bit overkill because I wanted to be able to render this feature to many elements though the example here only bothers with one :)

Here's the code!

```js
strictHoverStyle();

function strictHoverStyle(){
 let overTooltipTexts = false;
 let tooltipSet = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip');
 let tooltiptextSet = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltiptext');
 let tooltips = Array.from(tooltipSet);
 let tooltiptexts = Array.from(tooltiptextSet);

 for(let i = 0; i<tooltips.length; i++){
  tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
   if(overTooltipTexts){
    tooltiptexts[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    tooltiptexts[i].style.opacity = 'opacity 1s';
    tooltiptexts[i].style.transition = 0;
   } else{
    tooltiptexts[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    tooltiptexts[i].style.opacity = 1;
   }
  });

  tooltips[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
   tooltiptexts[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
   tooltiptexts[i].style.opacity = 0;
  });

  tooltiptexts[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
   overTooltipTexts = true;
  });

  tooltiptexts[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
   overTooltipTexts = false;
  });
 } 
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Strict Hover</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>
   <span class="tooltip">STRICT HOVER!<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></span>
  </h1> 
 </body>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```